# I am unable to access my WD external hard drive

Tags: 14.04, windows, mount, hard-drive

I am unable to access my WD external hard drive just after using 2/3 times. it's not working in both Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Windows. It's showing the following message. Please help me to access my hard drive. It contains very very important files so I can't format it.

```
Unable to mount My Passport
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdc1: Command-line `mount "/mnt/usb-WD_My_Passport_0810_57584D3145413443585A3144-0:0-part1"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Incomplete multi-sector transfer: magic: 0x58444e49  size: 4096  usa_ofs: 40  usa_count: 2  data: 5046  usn: 5045: Input/output error
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Windows message:

> The file or directory are corrupted and unreadable.

Comment: As stated: "The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting)". It is a problem generated by Windows and should be fixed within Windows. Dupe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: You can mount the disk as read-only and backup your data. And as the message tells you, you should use Windows to fix it if possible. Probably the FastBoot feature or any other type of cache of Windows was enabled on that drive that now keeps Ubuntu from getting full access. You should however be able to mount it with Windows and disable such features or run `chkdsk` there.

Answer (score 0):

try to fix it from commandline with

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdc1
```

unless your windows is hibernated: in this case, as Rinzwind suggested you, boot in Windows and shut down properly.

Cheers,

Silvia